# replace function causing issue with modal form

Tags: javascript, html, replace, nan

I am editing a dashboard for a CMS which contains a table of float values, displaying the financials of the services provided. An add service button will display a modal form which will allow the user to input data for a new service that will then be added to the table.

```
                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Wrong value : Can't be empty</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_services_group">Services group</label><input id="add_service_services_group" type="text" name="services_group" class="form-control" list="list_services_group">
                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;"><img src="/assets/images/loading.gif"/></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_quantity">Quantity </label><input type="number" id="add_service_quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                                <span class="help-block">Has to be a positive number</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_months">Months </label><input type="number" id="add_service_months" name="months" class="form-control">
                                <span class="help-block">Has to be a positive number</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_unit_sell">Unit cost (1 licence - X months)</label><span class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input type="number" id="add_service_unit_sell" name="unit_sell" class="form-control"></span>
                                <span class="help-block">Has to be a positive number or 0</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_invoice_date">Invoice date </label><input type="date" id="add_service_invoice_date" name="invoice_date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,(date("m")+1),01,date("Y"))); ?>">
                                <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Wrong value : Can't be empty</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="display:none">      
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_unit_buy">Unit buy</label><span class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input type="number" id="add_service_unit_buy" name="unit_buy" class="form-control"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_domain">Domain name </label><input type="text" id="add_service_domain" name="domain" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_registrar">Registrar name </label><input type="text" id="add_service_registrar" name="registrar" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_renewal_date">Renewal date </label><input type="date" id="add_service_renewal_date" name="renewal_date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,(date("m")+1),01,date("Y")+1)); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_notes">Notes </label><textarea id="add_service_notes" name="notes" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_invoice_type">Invoice type </label><input type="text" id="add_service_invoice_type" name="invoice_type" value="01_start+1m" class="form-control" list="list_invoice_type">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="add_service_invoice_notes">Invoice notes </label><textarea id="add_service_invoice_notes" name="invoice_notes" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div id="add_service_info"></div>
                <input class="btn btn-custom" type="submit" value="ADD" id="add_service_submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which calls a JavaScript function

```
    /**
     * Add a click event on the add services button to add the new service
     * Check the fields and correct some exceptions
     * Display a message at the bottom of the modal window in case of error
     * Load the services group after a customer is chosen
     * Load the default values for months and price after a service is selected
     **/
    if( $('#add_service_form').length ) {
        $('#add_service_submit').on('click', function () {
            var array_names = [
                'customer',
                'service',
                'services_group',
                'invoice_date',
                'renewal_date',
                'quantity',
                'unit_sell',
                'unit_buy',
                'months',
                'domain',
                'registrar',
                'notes',
                'invoice_notes',
                'invoice_type',
            ];

            var ref_form = document.forms['service_form']; //The reference on the form
            $('#add_service_info').empty().append('<img src="/assets/images/loading.gif" />'); //Display a loading image on the bottom

            var json_data = {};
            var valid = true;
            for( var i=0 ; i < array_names.length ; i++ ){
                var field_name = array_names[i]; //The name of the field
                var field_value = ref_form.elements[field_name].value.trim(); //The value of the field after removed the space at the beginning and at the end

                /* Remove the error alert in some fields */
                if( $(ref_form.elements[field_name]).parents('.form-group').hasClass('has-error') ){
                    $(ref_form.elements[field_name]).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').find('span.help-block').hide();
                }

                switch(field_name){
                    case 'customer':
                    case 'service':
                    case 'invoice_date':
                        if( field_value == '' ){ //The value can't be empty
                            $( ref_form.elements[field_name] ).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error').find('span.help-block').show();
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'renewal_date':
                        if( field_value == '' ) {
                            field_value = '0000-00-00';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'quantity':
                    case 'months':
                        if( field_value == '' || field_value < 1 ){ //The value has to be positive
                            $( ref_form.elements[field_name] ).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'unit_sell':
                        if( field_value == '' || field_value < 0 ){ //The value can't be empty or negative
                            $( ref_form.elements[field_name] ).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'unit_buy':    
                         if( field_value == '' || field_value < 0 ){ //The value can't be empty or negative
                            $( ref_form.elements[field_name] ).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                json_data[field_name] = field_value; //Record the value to send it to the server
            }

            if(!valid){
                //One or more fields have not been validated
                $('#add_service_info').empty();
                return ;
            }

            $.post(base_url+'services/add_service', json_data, function(result){
                if( result.added && (result.ID_inserted != false) ){
                    if( $('#table_services').length ){ //If the table exists we can add the new line
                        //ADD the new line
                        var table_API = $('#table_services').DataTable();
                        json_data['id'] = result.ID_inserted;//Record the ID inserted in the object added in the dataTable
                        json_data['total_sell'] = ( json_data['unit_sell'] * json_data['quantity'] ) ;
                        json_data['unit_buy'] = ( json_data['unit_buy'] ) ;                                 
                        json_data['total_buy'] = ( json_data['unit_buy'] * json_data['quantity'] ) ;       
                        json_data['monthly_sell'] = ( ( json_data['unit_sell'] * json_data['quantity'] ) / json_data['months'] ) ;
                        json_data['invoice_date'] = (typeof change_date_format == 'function') ? change_date_format(json_data['invoice_date'], '/') : json_data['invoice_date'] ;
                        json_data['renewal_date'] = (typeof change_date_format == 'function') ? change_date_format(json_data['renewal_date'], '/') : json_data['renewal_date'] ;
                        json_data['options'] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit edit_line"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open archive_line" ></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove delete_line"></span>'; //Add the option data to add on the table
                        var ref_new_row = table_API.row.add( json_data ).draw(); //Add the new row and get it

                        $( ref_new_row.node() ).attr('id','table_services_row_'+result.ID_inserted); //Add the id of the row
                        var array_columns = table_API.init().columns; //Array with the settings of the columns //CAN CAUSE ERROR AFTER DATATABLES UPDATE IF THEY CHANGED THE INIT RETURN
                        table_API.cells(ref_new_row,'').every(function() {
                            //For every cell we add the header attribute
                            //Used with the css style
                            var ref_cell = this;
                            var cell_name = array_columns[ref_cell.index().column].name; //The name of the column to use exceptions

                            $( ref_cell.node() ).attr('headers','table_services_'+cell_name); //Add the header attribute
                            if( cell_name == 'id' )
                                $( ref_cell.node() ).css('display','none'); //Hide the cell
                        });
                    }

                    $('#add_service_info').empty(); //Remove the loading image
                    $('#add_service_form').modal('hide'); //Hide the modal form

                    /* Change the value in the form - Empty or default value */
                    for( ref_element in ref_form.elements ){                                                                                   Services view - decimal places - test 6.4
                        ref_form.elements[ref_element].value = ""; //Set the null value in the form
                    }
                    var actual_date = new Date(); //An object of the actual date
                    var def_inv_date = new Date(actual_date.getFullYear(), actual_date.getMonth()+1, '01', '', '', '', ''); //The date for the year after
                    var def_ren_date = new Date(actual_date.getFullYear()+1, actual_date.getMonth()+1, '01', '', '', '', ''); //The date for the year after
                    ref_form.elements['invoice_date'].value = (typeof change_date_format == 'function') ? change_date_format(def_inv_date.toLocaleDateString(), '-') : ''; //The date at the good format, otherwise empty
                    ref_form.elements['renewal_date'].value = (typeof change_date_format == 'function') ? change_date_format(def_ren_date.toLocaleDateString(), '-') : '';//The renewal date at the good format, otherwise empty
                    ref_form.elements['quantity'].value = 1;
                    ref_form.elements['unit_sell'].value = 0;
                    ref_form.elements['unit_buy'].value = 0;   
                    ref_form.elements['months'].value = 1;
                    ref_form.elements['invoice_type'].value = '01_start+1m';
                    /* Change the value in the form - Empty or default value */
                }
                else{
                    //The function worked but the data has not been added in the database
                    $('#add_service_info').empty().addClass('alert alert-danger').append("ERROR adding a new service.<br />" + result.message);
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#add_service_info').removeClass('alert alert-danger').empty();
                    },10000);
                    return false;
                }
            },'json')
                .fail(function(jqXHR_object){
                    //An error happened when the function worked
                    $('#add_service_info').empty().addClass('alert alert-danger').append("FAIL adding the service.<br />Function error : Contact your administrator.<br />Status : " + jqXHR_object.status + " | StatusText : " +jqXHR_object.statusText);
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#add_service_info').removeClass('alert alert-danger').empty();
                    },10000);
                    return false;
                });

            return true;
        });
```

I have formatted the table to display 2 decimal points after each float. 
I have a function which will store the accumulated value of each row and display the total at the top menu.

```
 var table_api = this.api(); //The API reference of the table
            //Modify the select lists in the header
            var total_sell = 0;
            $.each(currData,function(key,element){
                total_sell += element.monthly_sell.replace(',','')*1.0;
            });
            $('#total_sell').text(parseFloat(total_sell).toFixed(2));

            //Total the amount spent on services 
            var total_buy = 0;
            $.each(currData,function(key,element){
                total_buy += element.total_buy.replace(',','')*1.0;
            });
            $('#total_buy').text(parseFloat(total_buy).toFixed(2));
```

Initially my total wasn't being displayed due to comma's in the values over 1000. I fixed this issue with the .replace() function to remove the first comma in the number.

However this has caused an issue with my "add service" modal form where after I select "add" the form is in a constant loading loop. The values are still added to the table if I hit the refresh button, but I can't figure out why the form won't minimise like it did
(note: If I remove the replace function, the "add service" modal form will work as normal but then my totals will display $NaN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single value in your data set that can't be converted to a number by multiplying *1 as you do (for example "1,200" or "$10"), it will affect the whole equation, always resulting in `NaN`. (see this https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls)

So you replace the comma, with `replace` method. But `replace` [is a method from the String class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). So now, if you have a single value in your dataset that is not a string (such as `undefined` or a number), your code will break because `replace` will not be available, so you will be stuck with the spinner forever from that point.

So my suggestion is that you make sure you are working with the right types:

```
var total_sell = 0;
$.each(currData,function(key,element){
    var item_sell = element.monthly_sell.toString().replace(',','')*1.0;
    if( !isNaN(item_sell) ) {
        total_sell += item_sell;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Not only did that work but your explanation of what was happening was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.monthly_sell.replace(',','')) replaces the first occurence of , in the string element.monthly_sell and returns the result string.
```

When *1.0 is done on string, it doesnot return a number. It returns NaN.
So, convert the string to number and try as below or use parseInt.

```js
 var table_api = this.api(); //The API reference of the table
            //Modify the select lists in the header
            var total_sell = 0;
            $.each(currData,function(key,element){
                total_sell += Number(element.monthly_sell.replace(',',''))*1.0;
            });
            $('#total_sell').text(parseFloat(total_sell).toFixed(2));

            //Total the amount spent on services 
            var total_buy = 0;
            $.each(currData,function(key,element){
                total_buy += Number(element.total_buy.replace(',',''))*1.0;
            });
            $('#total_buy').text(parseFloat(total_buy).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help with the form not minimising after submission but thanks for the helpful tips